# how to code to get facebook friend list in ios7

Tags: iphone, ios7

Hi am using following code

```
-(IBAction)FacebookFriendBtnClk:(id)sender
{
ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
__block ACAccount *facebookAccount = nil;

ACAccountType *facebookAccountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];

// Specify App ID and permissions
NSDictionary *options = @{
                          ACFacebookAppIdKey: @"743178525726332",
                          ACFacebookPermissionsKey: @[@"publish_stream", @"publish_actions",@"read_friendlists"],
                          ACFacebookAudienceKey: ACFacebookAudienceFriends
                          };

[accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:facebookAccountType
                                      options:options completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
 {
     if (granted)
     {
         NSArray *accounts = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:facebookAccountType];

         facebookAccount = [accounts lastObject];
     }
     else {

         NSLog(@"error.localizedDescription======= %@", error.localizedDescription);
     }

 }];

NSArray *accounts = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:facebookAccountType];
facebookAccount = [accounts lastObject];

//NSString *acessToken = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",facebookAccount.credential.oauthToken];
//NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"access_token": acessToken};

NSDictionary *param=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"picture,id,name,link,gender,last_name,first_name,username",@"fields", nil];

NSURL *feedURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends"];
SLRequest *feedRequest = [SLRequest
                          requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook
                          requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET
                          URL:feedURL
                          parameters:param];
feedRequest.account = facebookAccount;
[feedRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData,
                                         NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error)
 {
     if(!error)
     {
         id json =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

         NSLog(@"Dictionary contains data: %@", json );
         if([json objectForKey:@"error"]!=nil)
         {
             //[self attemptRenewCredentials];
         }
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
             //nameLabel.text = [json objectForKey:@"username"];
         });
     }
     else{
         //handle error gracefully
         NSLog(@"error from get%@",error);
         //attempt to revalidate credentials
     }
 }];
```

}

Am getting following error in log

```
  2014-04-04 16:49:04.098 ImageProcessingDemo[4791:3c0b] error.localizedDescription======= (null)
  2014-04-04 16:49:34.964 ImageProcessingDemo[4791:3f07] Dictionary contains data: {
error =     {
    code = 2500;
    message = "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.";
    type = OAuthException;
    };
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of the question you asked 4 hours earlier. Please just edit the original question rather than creating a new question when you want to add more information. [How to code to get facebook friendlist in ios7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22858839/how-to-code-to-get-facebook-friendlist-in-ios7)

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code :-

```
-(void)getFrndList
{
    @try
    {
        [app showIndicator:@"Loading..."];
        if (![FBSession activeSession].isOpen) {
            [FBSession renewSystemCredentials:^(ACAccountCredentialRenewResult result,
                                                NSError *error)
             {
                 if(error)
                 {
                     [app stopIndicator];
                 }
                 NSArray *permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"email", @"read_friendlists", @"user_photos", @"user_events", nil];
                 [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions
                                                    allowLoginUI:YES
                                               completionHandler:
                  ^(FBSession *session,
                    FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
                      if(error)
                      {
                          [app stopIndicator];
                      }
                      [self btnFriends:nil];
                  }];
             }];
        }
        else
        {
            [self btnFriends:nil];
        }
    }
    @catch (NSException *e) {

    }
}


-(IBAction)btnFriends:(id)sender
{

    FBRequest* friendsRequest = [FBRequest requestForMyFriends];
    [friendsRequest startWithCompletionHandler: ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                                          NSDictionary* result,
                                                          NSError *error) {
    NSArray* friends = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
    [arrFacebookFriends removeAllObjects];
    NSLog(@"Found: %i friends", friends.count);
    for (NSDictionary<FBGraphUser>* friend in friends) {
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [dict setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",friend.first_name,friend.last_name] forKey:dictkeyName];
    [dict setValue:friend.id forKey:dictkeyId];
    [dict setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=large",friend.id] forKey:dictkeyImage];
    [arrFacebookFriends addObject:dict];
    NSLog(@"I have a friend named %@ with id %@", friend.name, friend.id);

    }


     [app stopIndicator];
     }];

}
```

Comment: how to declare FBSession

Comment: hi am using social frame work how to solve this error

Comment: You need to integrate facebooksdk.framework for using this code. You can able to download it from developer.facebook.com.Just dnwload that framework and drag and drop in your project

Comment: after drag and drop which file we want to import

Comment: You need to import #import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>

Comment: am download facebook -ios-sdk-3.13.pkg  then what next step

Comment: Use this link :- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/ and if your problem is solved than accept the answer

Comment: "use undeclare idetifire DictKeyName"

Comment: i tri @impossible code but now showing 0 friends in friend list